# Retrofit registering gson and jackson converter factories

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson, retrofit2

I have a legacy project that is using both jackson and gson deserializers.  I would like to use retrofit to parse data from either.  However the problem is that neither the *JacksonConverterFactory* or *GsonConverterFactory* return null for the responseBodyConverter.  IE here is the jackson impl:

```
  @Override
  public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(
      Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(type);
    ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(javaType);
    return new JacksonResponseBodyConverter<>(reader);
  }
```

I would like to use Jackson in the case where I have registered a deserializer, ie:

```
val module = SimpleModule()
module.addDeserializer(User::class.java, UserDeserializer())

val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
objectMapper.registerModule(module)

val converterFactory = JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper)
```

So in this case if a user is being deserialized, use Jackson, otherwise skip and look at next registered converter factory, in this case gson.

I get that since *JacksonConverterFactory* never returns null, such that the converter factory will be skipped I would need to write my own ConverterFactory impl.  I am looking for a way in jackson to look at the mappers module and determine if there is a customer deserializer.  However form the docs and public API I cannot seem to find the registered deserializers.

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: _> However form the docs and public API I cannot seem to find the registered deserializers._ Most likely because neither Jackson nor Gson were designed to cooperate with other similar libraries. What you could do is implementing a custom response body converter that would dispatch a correct factory method depending on the given input types. It looks like it's pretty much doable by implementing a builder pattern to build certain rules the converting dispatcher would work upon.

Comment: There has got to be a way with the jackson API to ask what custom deserializers have been registered for a type.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the way the API can be asked. I'm not an expert in Jackson, but for Gson there is no way to ask it and get either `true` or `false`: there's simply no such API. It can be however inferred from the returned type adapters classes. In Jackson I saw there is a "canDeserialize" method that can tell either true or false, but I'm not sure whether it will work for you since it returns `true` before and after registering a deserializing module for me. `SimpleModule` has some protected fields you can access in an extending class too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean but as far as I understood you want to use **both** of the converter factories and customize them up to your liking. If that is the case, you can take a look at this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson.
Hope that could help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33674804)